# Vertically align InputGroupAddon in dash dashboard with Python

Tags: python, html, css, plotly, plotly-dash

I am working on a dash dashboard. I am using some `dash_bootstrap_components` [InputGroup](https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/docs/components/input_group/). This is what I have done until now:

[image]

I would like to vertically align the `InputGroupAddon` `'prepend'` and the `InputGroupAddon` `'append'` of the `InputGroup`, something like:

[image]

I want to stretch the `dbc.InputGroupAddon` `'prepend'` and the `dbc.InputGroupAddon` `'append'` width and let the dbc.Input automatically adjust to fill the width.
I want to keep the overall width to `400`.
Here is my code:

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc


n = 19
v_min = 0
v_max = 10
v_step = 1
v_0 = 5


app = dash.Dash(external_stylesheets = [dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])

app.layout = html.Div(id = 'general_div',
                      children = [html.Div(id = 'options_div',
                                           children = [dbc.InputGroup([dbc.InputGroupAddon(children = 'Option A',
                                                                                           addon_type = 'prepend'),
                                                                       dbc.Input(id = 't_ON_input',
                                                                                 type = 'number',
                                                                                 min = v_min,
                                                                                 max = v_max,
                                                                                 step = v_step,
                                                                                 value = v_0),
                                                                       dbc.InputGroupAddon(children = 'unit',
                                                                                           addon_type = 'append')]),

                                                       dbc.InputGroup([dbc.InputGroupAddon(children = 'Option B',
                                                                                           addon_type = 'prepend'),
                                                                       dbc.Input(id = 't_OFF_input',
                                                                                 type = 'number',
                                                                                 min = v_min,
                                                                                 max = v_max,
                                                                                 step = v_step,
                                                                                 value = v_0),
                                                                       dbc.InputGroupAddon(children = 'an other unit',
                                                                                           addon_type = 'append')]),

                                                       dbc.InputGroup([dbc.InputGroupAddon(children = 'Some text here',
                                                                                           addon_type = 'prepend'),
                                                                       dbc.Input(id = 'T_start_input',
                                                                                 type = 'number',
                                                                                 min = v_min,
                                                                                 max = v_max,
                                                                                 step = v_step,
                                                                                 value = v_0),
                                                                       dbc.InputGroupAddon(children = 'something',
                                                                                           addon_type = 'append')]),

                                                       dbc.InputGroup([dbc.InputGroupAddon(children = 'Last option',
                                                                                           addon_type = 'prepend'),
                                                                       dbc.Input(id = 'voltage_input',
                                                                                 type = 'number',
                                                                                 min = v_min,
                                                                                 max = v_max,
                                                                                 step = v_step,
                                                                                 value = v_0),
                                                                       dbc.InputGroupAddon(children = 'last unit',
                                                                                           addon_type = 'append')])],

                                           style = {'display': 'inline-block',
                                                    'vertical-align': 'top',
                                                    'margin-left': '3vw',
                                                    'margin-top': '3vw',
                                                    'width': 400})])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server()
```

I have tried to specify the `'width'` under the `style` parameter like this:

```
dbc.InputGroupAddon(children = 'Option A',
                    addon_type = 'prepend',
                    style = {'width': 200}),
dbc.Input(id = 't_ON_input',
          type = 'number',
          min = v_min,
          max = v_max,
          step = v_step,
          value = v_0),
dbc.InputGroupAddon(children = 'unit',
                    addon_type = 'append')
```

but I get this:

[image]

The `dbc.InputGroup` is broken between `dbc.InputGroupAddon` and `dbc.Input`.

Version info

```
Python                       3.7.0
dash                         1.12.0
dash-bootstrap-components    0.10.1
dash-html-components         1.0.3
```

Comment: You might want to specify `style = {'width': 200}` as `style = {'width': '200px'}`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Just tried, not worked, I got the same issue as above

Comment: Looks like you need to write custom css and invoke using `className=<>` in the inputAddon part. Otherwise it takes default size of the text within the label.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally managed to solve the issue.
I have assigned a class to the text spans and linked a local `css` stylesheet (located in the folder `assets\`):

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc


n = 19
v_min = 0
v_max = 10
v_step = 1
v_0 = 5


app = dash.Dash(external_stylesheets = [dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP, 'box_style.css'])


app.layout = html.Div(id = 'general_div',
                      children = [html.Div(id = 'options_div',
                                           children = [dbc.InputGroup([dbc.InputGroupAddon(children = html.Span(children = 'Option A',
                                                                                                                className = 'prepend-text'),
                                                                                           addon_type = 'prepend'),
                                                                       dbc.Input(id = 't_ON_input',
                                                                                 type = 'number',
                                                                                 min = v_min,
                                                                                 max = v_max,
                                                                                 step = v_step,
                                                                                 value = v_0),
                                                                       dbc.InputGroupAddon(children = html.Span(children = 'unit',
                                                                                                                className = 'append-text'),
                                                                                           addon_type = 'append')]),

                                                       dbc.InputGroup([dbc.InputGroupAddon(children = html.Span(children = 'Option B',
                                                                                                                className = 'prepend-text'),
                                                                                           addon_type = 'prepend'),
                                                                       dbc.Input(id = 't_OFF_input',
                                                                                 type = 'number',
                                                                                 min = v_min,
                                                                                 max = v_max,
                                                                                 step = v_step,
                                                                                 value = v_0),
                                                                       dbc.InputGroupAddon(children = html.Span(children = 'another unit',
                                                                                                                className = 'append-text'),
                                                                                           addon_type = 'append')]),

                                                       dbc.InputGroup([dbc.InputGroupAddon(children = html.Span(children = 'Some text here',
                                                                                                                className = 'prepend-text'),
                                                                                           addon_type = 'prepend'),
                                                                       dbc.Input(id = 'T_start_input',
                                                                                 type = 'number',
                                                                                 min = v_min,
                                                                                 max = v_max,
                                                                                 step = v_step,
                                                                                 value = v_0),
                                                                       dbc.InputGroupAddon(children = html.Span(children = 'something',
                                                                                                                className = 'append-text'),
                                                                                           addon_type = 'append')]),

                                                       dbc.InputGroup([dbc.InputGroupAddon(children = html.Span(children = 'Last option',
                                                                                                                className = 'prepend-text'),
                                                                                           addon_type = 'prepend'),
                                                                       dbc.Input(id = 'voltage_input',
                                                                                 type = 'number',
                                                                                 min = v_min,
                                                                                 max = v_max,
                                                                                 step = v_step,
                                                                                 value = v_0),
                                                                       dbc.InputGroupAddon(children = html.Span(children = 'last unit',
                                                                                                                className = 'append-text'),
                                                                                           addon_type = 'append')])],

                                           style = {'display': 'inline-block',
                                                    'vertical-align': 'top',
                                                    'margin-left': '3vw',
                                                    'margin-top': '3vw',
                                                    'width': 400})])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server()
```

I copied the stylesheet class from the dash default and added `width`, `border-radius` and  `text-align` properties (`width` is the key property to solve the above mentioned issue, the rest is for further aesthetic adjustments). Here my local css:

```
.prepend-text {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: .375rem .75rem;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #495057;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color: #e9ecef;
    border: 1px solid #ced4da;
    width: 150px;
    border-top-left-radius: 0.25rem;
    border-top-right-radius: 0rem;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0rem;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0.25rem;
}

.form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(1.5em + .75rem + 2px);
    padding: .375rem .75rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #495057;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid #ced4da;
    border-radius: 0rem;
    transition: border-color .15s ease-in-out,box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
    width: 130px;
    text-align: right;
}

.append-text {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: .375rem .75rem;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #495057;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color: #e9ecef;
    border: 1px solid #ced4da;
    width: 120px;
    border-top-left-radius: 0rem;
    border-top-right-radius: 0.25rem;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0.25rem;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0rem;
}
```

Which gives me this layout:

[image]

Comment: Appreciate this.  Helped me with a similar problem.

Comment: Lifesaving solution!